# Where to install Angular on Apache?

Tags: angularjs, apache, webserver

First of all, my question is **not about how to install angular**. I'm just getting started with this framework and already got a question right at the beginning.

Usually I create new web projects (HTML, PHP...) in the default web folder of the apache webserver (`/var/www/`). I did this with angular too under `/var/www/firstAngularProject`, but it seems the application itself is only accessible on its default port on the webserver root. In my case this is `localhost:4200`

When I try to open the path in my browser `localhost/firstAngularProject` I see the index structure and I think this could become a security issue.

So my question is where should I install the angular project or what is the usual way to install it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run Angular using the cli command `ng start` (which I assume, based on you describing using `localhost:4200`) you're running the application using webpack-dev-server. This is undesirable since it's only meant for use during development, not for production.

In production Angular works just like any other frontend framework. You build the application with `ng build --prod` which produces a number of build artifact (in the `/dist` folder). These artifact are simply static files you make available through some webserver, in your case Apache, by **copying the content of the `/dist` folder to `/var/www`** (or whichever is your default web folder) and that's about it.

Comment: That means, I can develop the application on my local machine and when I'm ready I build it, get some files and upload these files to the actual webserver?

Comment: Yes, you only have to upload the contents of the `/dist` folder. In the end, an Angular application is just html, js, css and image files.

Comment: So there is also no need to install the angular framework on the webserver?

Comment: Nope. None at all.